# How to calculate magnetic field of the coil?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I got a coil of $200 \mu H$

[image]

I applied nearly $1 V$ to it and got a current of $2 A$.

How to calculate magnetic field of it (in Teslas)?

I don't know number of turns. Is this required?

Comment: How about looking up "magnetic field of a coil" which would get you for example to this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid where you get a formular for the magnetic field. And yes you would need the number of turns as well as the relative permeability of the  immersed material and the current. There might be several ways to measure it with improvised tools but maybe even an estimate for the number of turns as well as the relative permeability of the  immersed material would give better results.

Comment: The problem with solenoid is that it is obvious. Additionally, solenoid has winding in one layer. Here we have multiple layer. We know only inductance. If it is impossible to calculate magnetic field in the case, then I would like to know the reason of this?

Comment: You could use the formular for the inductance of a solenoid and an estimate for $\mu_r$ with the cross-section area $A$ to get an 'effective' value for the winding number and use that to calculate $B$. That would be one way to get an approximation. If you realy want to deal with the theory of multilayer coils you could look at https://www.researchgate.net/publication/222492899_Multilayer_Gradient_Coil_Design and/or specify the question towards that topic.